# Planetary (Venus) coordinate reference systems

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, venus

I'm trying to understanding the projections and trying to load in Venus global map data but when I try to align different maps with the same projection, or even change projection, I consistently get the error "No transform available between XXXX and Custom CRS”. I should create a “basemap” or so?